# Problems installing lubuntu, specificaly with grub on the installation

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, lubuntu, 22.04

I have an old Samsung RV511 notebook. I changed the hard drive with a blank one, and tried to install Lubuntu. I used to run Windows 10 and for a short period with a dual boot with Ubuntu, but now after running just Windows for a number of years it seems that no distro can install grub or make any bootloader work unless it's installing Windows. I tried all types of recovery for bootloaders, but nothing seems to work.

Lubuntu gives me this message every time I tried to install it:

```
O carregador de inicialização não pôde ser instalado. 
O comando de instalação grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi --bootloader-id=ubuntu --force retornou o código de erro 1.
```

It's very weird. Could it be that I need a new CMOS battery?

Comment: You weren't specific as to which Lubuntu 22.04 ISO you used as 22.04 & 22.04.1 use different versions of `calamares` and thus I'd ensure you tried the later one if you used the earlier ISO (the newer `calamares` was SRU'd there for a reason!)  Note:  *this may not be your issue, & I'm not good with boot loader problems, but as trying the different version is pretty easy & have seen the consequences of the different code on each 22.04 ISO it's something I'd try*

Comment: Another thought:   Ensure you wrote your ISO to your installation media correctly; either following the Lubuntu manual (https://manual.lubuntu.me/lts/1/Installing_lubuntu.html) as most times I've had issues as you describe, it was because of users writing the ISO using different tools that adjusted the ISO to achieve something but it also created issues that caused `grub-install` to misread the system (*as installation media when written correctly will be ignored*). Your installation summary screen should reflect such issues prior to install.

Comment: The specs look like it would be an early UEFI implementation. So you probably can install in UEFI boo tmode or BIOS boot mode. If drive is gpt partitioned (recommended) you need an ESP - efi system partition for UEFI install or a bios_grub partition if BIOS boot. The error is related to grub's UEFI boot file not installing. Some UEFI also have setting that lock ESP or prevent boot installer from installing. Check UEFI/BIOS settings.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. It is important to know if your computer has a BIOS or UEFI. Make your bootable device according to what your computer runs. If you have a BIOS make your bootable device in MBR/BIOS mode. If your device runs UEFI make it in GPT/UEFI mode. I had some issues installing it on an old Acer desktop. My setup media was made in UEFI mode, while the computer had a BIOS. Took me a day to figure that mistake out.

Comment: @HomerSimpson, I QA test Ubuntu Desktop ISOs somewhat heavily, and I use the same burnt ISO on media to install in legacy BIOS machines, uEFI machines and Secure-uEFI machines...   If written correctly, Ubuntu ISOs will boot & install on all *amd64* hardware regardless of BIOS/uEFI/Secure-uEFI.  Some software re-formats the ISO which is why it'll only boot on specific boxes, which can be useful for some boxes (*so as to make it boot faster for example if your box has firmware bugs*) but it also reduces what the thumb-drive will boot from.

Comment: @guiverc Thanks for your response. I use Ventoy, so I can use multiple iso's, and found out that with this software it is important. I haven't tried it with other software. I don't know what software the OP uses, therefor my comment.